# Pie chart doesn't show low percentages on it

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I've been trying Google's Chart API for a time, it works like a charm for my needs but I figured out that when using pie chart with low percentages the library doesn't display the lower ones.

I tried to reduce fontSize property, it works for certain values (example http://jsfiddle.net/73tnp7ot/2/) but for lower ones the library doesn't display them, for the example given if I change values from 4 to 2 percentage will not be displayed.

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Gender', 'Overall'],
    ['M', 128],
    ['F', 2]
]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5rd751hx/5/

I need the percentage to be displayed, this is because I have to export the chart to an image.

Is there a way to display low percentages inside or outside the pie?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you checked `sliceVisibilityThreshold` from the [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#configuration-options)?

Comment: I did and the same, with low percentages it doesn't display them.
Another option was to use legend labeled but when there are a lot of values it doesn't appear lines to those pieces of chart

Comment: I believe your only option would be to change the size of the chart, In your fiddle, setting the body to 100% and the label is there.